# AngularJS call Rest Api: TypeError

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I am calling restful service from AngularJS. HTML is very basic with a input text box and a button for query.

// basic.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cgApp" >
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/service.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="CgseqCtrl">
        <input ng-model="analysisid"><button ng-click="searchById()">Search</button>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>{{seq.analysisId}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.center}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.diseaseAbbr}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.filepath}}</td>
                <td>{{seq.library}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I use a service to call rest api

```
// service.js
app.factory("Cgseq", function ($http) {
    // return $resource('http://localhost:8080/cgweb/api/seqs/fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009');
    var service = {};
    service.getSeqById = function(analysisid) {
        return http.get('http://localhost:8080/cgweb/api/seqs/' + analysisid);
    }


    service.getSeq = function() {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/cgweb/api/seqs/fdebfd6e-d046-4192-8b97-ac9f65dc2009');
    }

    return service;
});
```

The function `searchById()` will be executed once the button is clicked. It is implemented in my controller.

```
// controller.js
var app = angular.module('cgApp', [])

app.controller('CgseqCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cgseq', function($scope, Cgseq){
    $scope.searchById() = function() {
        CgSeq.getSeqById($scope.analysisid)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.seq = response;
        });
    }
}]);
```

When I load basic.html in a browser, even before I type in something in the input box and click the button, I got the following error:

```
angular.js:12416 TypeError: $scope.searchById is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (controller.js:8)
```

Comment: You try using $scope.searchById = function() {....} Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the `()` from `$scope.searchById() = function`

And correct the typo (case-sensitivity) for `Cgseq`
I.e.:

```
$scope.searchById = function() {
    Cgseq.getSeqById($scope.analysisid)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.seq = response;
    });
}
```